# I cannot access the localhost, can someone help me to solve the bug?

Tags: npm, command, localhost

[image]

[image]

This is my node command. can someone tell me what is going on? I am beginner

Comment: Post your code too

Answer (score 0):

Your Route is not set for / -- that's Why that is happening.. Read some Route related Docs